# Implementing custom h264 quantization for Ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, compression, video-streaming, h.264

I have a Raspberry Pi, and I'm livestreaming using FFmpeg. Unfortunately my wifi signal varies over the course of my stream. I'm currently using raspivid to send h264 encoded video to the stream. I have set a constant resolution and FPS, but have not set bitrate nor quantization, so they are variable.

However, the issue is that the quantization doesn't vary enough for my needs. If my wifi signal drops, my ffmpeg streaming speed will dip below 1.0x to 0.95xish for minutes, but my bitrate drops so slowly that ffmpeg can never make it back to 1.0x. As a result my stream will run into problems and start buffering.

I would like the following to happen:
If Ffmpeg (my stream command)'s reported speed goes below 1.0x (slower than realtime streaming), then increase quantization compression (lower bitrate) exponentially until Ffmpeg speed stabilizes at 1.0x. Prioritize stabilizing at 1.0x as quickly as possible.

My understanding is that the quantization logic Ffmpeg is using should be in the h264 encoder, but I can't find any mention of quantization at all in this github: https://github.com/cisco/openh264
My knowledge of h264 is almost zilch, so I'm trying to figure out

A) How does h264 currently vary the quantization during my stream, if at all?

B) Where is that code?

C) How hard is it for me to implement what I'm describing?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which encoder? ffmpeg has no native h.264 encoder.  Have you tried applying the fast presets? `-preset fast` or faster or veryfast, ultrafast..etc

Comment: I'm using the raspberry pi's built-in h264 encoder (in raspivid). However, if I have more flexibility within ffmpeg, i'd be happy to use ffmpeg's omx_h264 instead. I am not currently encoding with ffmpeg, only copying and muxing audio/video. However, took a look at preset and it didn't seem like what I was looking for? My internet speed changes during the stream, so I can't just have 1 compression setting for the whole stream. My compression needs to increase when my wifi slows and my ffmpeg speed falls behind realtime 1.0x.